# Альтернативы Spring integrations framework

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduler, spring-integration

У меня есть задача на чтение входных данных из http-источника (Twitter-канал) каждые 20 минут.
Я бы хотел узнать какие есть способы организации такой логики, помимо Spring integrations.

Возможно есть библиотеки или фреймворки, чтобы сделать такое расписание. Буду очень благодарен за ссылки или примеры. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению Ваш вопрос не ясен: Вы указываете Spring Boot, но при этом Вы против Spring Integration. Пожалуйста, поясните.

Можно Вашу задачу решить с помощью `@Scheduled` и ручного вызова REST-сервиса: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling

Но стоит ли, если Spring Integration с его inbound channel adapter + poller может позволить Вам делать такой вызов, а также распределить логику по дальнейшим конечным точкам через service activators и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего сделать на @Scheduled, если не нужно логировать джобы и более сложный функционал

Для сложных решений есть -  Quartz, Spring Batch, Spring Integration